# How to use all disk space available on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, dual-boot

I'm new to Linux and Linux Mint - but I recently flashed Linux Mint on my 16 GB USB drive (dual-boot), and for some reason Linux Mint is giving me warnings that there's no space left.

When I go to check how much disk space is available, it's saying that there's only **8.3 GB** of space available in total, where there should be ***16 GB.***
[image: Screenshot of the "Devices & Locations" window showing disk usage]

[image: Screenshot of the "Disks" window showing partitions]

How do I get Linux to use all of the space on my USB?

Am I doing something wrong, or am I just misunderstanding something?

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the output of `df -h`, `lsblk`, `mount` and `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: It looks like you created a small partition and are not using the rest of your drive.

Comment: Since it says sdc1 is ISO9660, that is a live installer. You cannot edit / or change / files as live installer is just like a DVD/CD that cannot be changed. You may also have persistence partition to store added info when using live installer. If you want a full install which you then can update & use, you need another drive/partition to install from your live installer flash drive.